# jQuery loop through table to display values

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach, html-table

I'm at a loss here. 
I created a quick script that will add a new row to a table and also has the capability to delete a row.

jsFiddle -->http://jsfiddle.net/wLpJr/10/

What I want to achieve is this:
Display each value of each row (in the div with id='thedata')

I originally started off with adding a number at the end of each id, starting at '1', and incrementing each time the user adds a row.

```
 //This is random code
 var rowcount = parseInt($('#rowcount').val());
 var newcount = rowcount + (1*1);
 var x = $('#radioinput' + newcount).val('a value');
 $('#rowcount').val(newcount);
```

The problem is that lets say you add 5 rows. Now delete row 3. When you loop through the table of data you will get an error because row "3" does not exist. You have rows 1, 2, 4, 5, 6. Specifically - the input with id = 'radioinput3' will not be present.

I then decided to do this:

```
 $('#maintable > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        radiovalue[i] = $("input[type='hidden']", this).map(function() {
            var vid = 'radio' + i;
            var myval = this.value;
            var radioinput = document.createElement("input");
                radioinput.type = "hidden";
                radioinput.value = myval; // set the CSS class
                radioinput.id = vid;
                $('#maintable').append(radioinput);
        }).get()
        text1value[i] = $('td > input', this).map(function() {
            var vid = 'text1pos' + i;
            var myval = this.value;
            var text1input = document.createElement('input');
            text1input.type='hidden';
            text1input.value = myval;
            text1input.id = vid;
            $('#maintable').append(text1input);
        }).get()
        text2value[i] = $('td > input', this).map(function() {
            var vid = 'text2pos' + i;
            var myval = this.value;
            var text2input = document.createElement('input');
            text2input.type='hidden';
            text2input.value = myval;
            text2input.id = vid;
            $('#maintable').append(text2input);
        }).get();
    });
```

The problem here is that I'm getting 'undefined' values.

Comment: variable `i` was not defined? did you forget to add parameter `i, item` of the function that you were passing onto `$.each`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through a counter, which you increment everytime you add a new row, but do not take into account that a row can be deleted at any time. Instead, just use the `each` function to loop over the elements remaining in the DOM.

Add `thead` and `tbody` tags to your table, it will make your life easier.

I'm not sure why you have those hidden div to hold the `input[type=radio]` values, you don;t need them, access the values directly.

```
$('#showdata').click(function() {
    $("#maintable tbody tr").each(function(i, v) {
        var myp = "<p>Radio value is = " + $(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
                    + "\nText1 value is = " + $(this).find('input[id$=text1]').val() 
                    + "\nText2 value is = " + $(this).find('input[id$=text2]').val() + "</p>";
        $('#thedata').append(myp);

    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/wLpJr/11/)

You could add a CSS class to the input text fields to make it easier to get, but i just used the [jQuery ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector.

Also, you delete selector if far too high up the DOM tree on `(document)`, instead restrict it as near as you can, in this case the `#maintable`.

Comment: I thought that when you create DOM elements you cannot select them with a selector so you have to use $(document).on('click', '#myid..

Comment: No, not quite. What doesn't work is trying to attach event handlers directly to elements which do not exist on `$(document).ready()` (you can't attach to what isn't there). So you use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), attach to a parent element you know will be there on DOM ready, and then "keep an eye on the children", even new ones that are added, since you are catching the events that bubble up. Of course you can do it at `document` level, but it is not the best performance.

Comment: Thanks man. If you offer a class in jquery let me know and I'll be there. :)